# DevExpress NavBarControl style: Change animation speed to expand/collapse groups

Tags: wpf, animation, styles, devexpress

Topic is self explanatory.

I found xaml code to do it for an Expander, I found default styles on the DevExpress website so you can change it, but nowhere do I find the right RoutedEvent or property to simply change the animation speed so it instantly collapses/expands.

I think it should be something like the code below, as I found for an Expander style. But I don't know the RoutedEvent that's needed.
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraNavBarNavBarControl_GroupExpandedtopic

Seems to be the event, but it doesn't work if I use it in my xaml.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<dxnav:NavBarControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GroupExpanded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.0" Storyboard.TargetName="navBarControl1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</dxnav:NavBarControl.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you simply want to change the default animation. Check the answer to this question: [NavBarGroup speed](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q237940)

Comment: Oh my how could I have missed that topic >< Thank you so much! Works perfectly :)